# Understanding IR Sensor Module

Tags: circuit-design, infrared

I am having a IR Sensor Module which i had got in a Robotics kit.
But it has a connector similar to RJ-45,

I wanted to use it with my arduino and hence wanted to desolder that jack and use jumper cables instead, but i m not sure what terminals 6 terminals of that module are.....

i observed that there are two IC - LM358(comparator) and IC - NE555 (timer).

can you pls help me undersanting these 6 teminals inside that square are... one might be vcc and other gnd....what about others???

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we number the pins looking at your 1st pic with the top row being 1 2 3 and the bottom row being 4 5 6, then the pinout is probably:
1 - Gnd
2 - nc
3 - nc
4 - power
5 - output
6 - nc

I've drawn these conclusions because:
Pin 1 is connected to pin 1 on the 555 and pin 4 on the LM358.
Pin 4 is connected to pin 8 on the 555 and (maybe) pin 8 on the LM358.
Pin 5 is connected to pin 7 on the LM358.